# What is wrong with opening and closing a stream like this?

Tags: java, try-catch

So I wrote some code and Netbeans suggests convert to try-with-resources on the same line I instantiate sc . This suggestion pops up the moment I put the sc.close() after the while-loop. I don't quite understand why this close-operation is badly placed.

```
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
         try{
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
             while(sc.hasNext()){
                 System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
             }
             sc.close();

         } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
             System.out.println("Het bestand kon niet gevonden worden.");
         } catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Onbekende Fout");
         }
    }
```

Comment: There's something called `finally`.

Comment: It's not in the while loop the close-operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you may not close `sc`, if you return from your `try` block or an exception occurs.

The try-with-resources version is best if you're using Java 7 or higher:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Het bestand kon niet gevonden worden.");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Onbekende Fout");
    }
}
```

The scanner will get closed automagically.

If you have to use Java 6 or earlier, then try/finally:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Het bestand kon niet gevonden worden.");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Onbekende Fout");
    }
    finally {
        if (sc != null) {
            try {
                sc.close();
            }
            catch (Exception) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the try/finally version, we declare `sc` outside the `try` block and set it to `null`, and then in the `finally` (which will run regardless of what happens in the `try`), we close it if it's not `null` *without allowing that operation to throw an exception* (because we may already be in the process of throwing an exception, and don't want to interrupt that).

Comment: My teach gave this sample code:
      try {
            bestand = new Scanner(new File(bestandsnaam)); 
            openengelukt = true;
   while (bestand.hasNextLine()) {
               System.out.println(bestand.nextLine());
            }
            bestand.close();
            console.close();
Looking at it ,it appears she made the mistake as well since it should be autoclosed?

Comment: It is not a mistake, it is a convenience.

Comment: It is a mistake, the code is wrong. I've just spent the last week combing through a massive project and fixing errors just like this because the thing was leaking resources like a sieve.

Comment: @BURNS: That's not a try-with-resources. (You can tell by looking at the first non-whitespace character after the `try`: If it's `{`, it's a standard `try` block; if it's `(`, it's a try-with-resources.) In a standard `try`, sometimes people issue the `close` call within the `try` block and `null` out the variable, rather than letting the `finally` handle it. A *really thorough* solution without try-with-resources would allow `close` to throw an exception, but only if we weren't already handling one, but it really complicates things. Which is why we have try-with-resources.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if anything inbetween the open and the close returns from the method or throws an exception then the close doesn't get called.

Using a try-with-resources (or pre Java 7 try-finally) to do the close guarantees that the stream gets closed every single time.

Comment: What if he doesnt write sc.close(). Why dont we get an exception that the resource is open?. If we are not able to execute sc.close() ,why is it not the same as as not having sc.close() in the code ?

Comment: try-with-resources is Java 7, not 8

Comment: @RossDrew oops, meant to type 7 there...no idea why I put 8. Fixed it thanks.

Comment: @TheLostMind I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

This way is better. Use of `finally` is provide safe operation.

```
    Scanner sc=null;
    try{
        sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }           

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Het bestand kon niet gevonden worden.");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Onbekende Fout");
    } finally {
        if(sc!=null){
        sc.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `sc.close()` from the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

`close()` should be done only when you're finished with the resource.  If you have an exception while reading for example then you will jump out of the block and skip the `close()`.
Add a `finally` block, this means it will either catch the exception then call `close()` or complete the `try` block then call `close()`

```
     Scanner sc = null;
     try{
         sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
         while(sc.hasNext()){
             System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
         }

     } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
         System.out.println("Het bestand kon niet gevonden worden.");
     } catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Onbekende Fout");
     }
     finally
     {
        if (sc != null)
          sc.close()
     }
```

or if you are using Java 7 a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is much simpler as it will do the close for you.

```
 try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));)
 {
  ....
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but that won't compile. `sc` is an undefined symbol in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

From Java Tutorial on [Try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
>   ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any
>   object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all
>   objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

**Example**

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

> In this example, the resource declared in the try-with-resources
>   statement is a BufferedReader. The declaration statement appears
>   within parentheses immediately after the try keyword. The class
>   BufferedReader, in Java SE 7 and later, implements the interface
>   java.lang.AutoCloseable. Because the BufferedReader instance is
>   declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed
>   regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly
>   (as a result of the method BufferedReader.readLine throwing an
>   IOException).

So try with resource will take care of closing your resource.You don't need to write `close()` any more.

Answer (score 0):

Assume reading the input fails at this line for whatever reason:

```
System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

An exception is thrown and the `catch (Exception e)` block is executed. You `Scanner` won't be closed in this situation.

To close the `Scanner` in all situations you should move the `sc.close()` statement to the finally block:

```
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    } 
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Het bestand kon niet gevonden worden.");
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Onbekende Fout");
} finally {
    if (sc != null) {
        try {
            sc.close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

For this you can now use the Try-with-Resource shortcut introduced with Java 7:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
    while(sc.hasNext()){
         System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
     }
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){
     System.out.println("Het bestand kon niet gevonden worden.");
} catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Onbekende Fout");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is anything that is returned in between the `open()` and `close()`, the method throws an Exception then `close()` is not being called. Do one thing try commenting the snippet and replacing with a other piece of code just to check whether the fault can be overridden with that. Alternatively, Use the try-with-resources which has been released after Java 7, this will ensure that `close()` gets used every time the stream is invoked.

Comment: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)